# Align center images on gallery width<767 CSS Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, center

I have a gallery made with Bootstrap 3 by a grid of 4x2, this looks perfect until the width is less than 767px and higher than 430px. It should look a single centered image but looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOZQF.png).

I have already tried with margin: 0 auto; and there have been no changes.
I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Please provide code instead of images so that it’ll be easier for us to show what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 'col-xs-12' to your bootstrap wrappers of the images, making it look like this:

```
class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 retrato isotope-item'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! SOLVED!